# Join 4 different tables with one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, management-studio-express

I have a table 1 where I need to join with other 4 tables. Can I write the same query using subqueries? Because if I am using below query it is taking long time (more than 40 mins) for running.
Is there any other way for this?

```
select T1.ID as IID, T2.Prokey as Pro, T3.pname as IType, T4.pname as Status, T5.pname as Res
from table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 on T1.pro = T2.ID
INNER JOIN table3 T3 on T1.itype =T3.ID
INNER JOIN table4 T4 on T1.itatus = T4.ID
INNER JOIN Table5 T5 on T1.Res = T5.ID
group by T2.ID, convert(nvarchar(max), T2.ID), T1.ID, T1.Pkey, T3.pname, T4.pname, T5.pname
```

Comment: Be sure you have indexes on all the `id` columns.  In fact, they should be declared as primary keys.

Comment: how can I include indexes for the above query? @GordonLinoff

Comment: joins are faster than subqueries.. so you should search for indexing

Comment: where can I create indexing in the above query? @kapil.dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the SQL statement:

```
-- CREATE TABLE 1 INDEXES 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table1_pro
ON Table1 (pro) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table1_itype 
ON Table1 (itype) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table1_itatus
ON Table1 (itatus) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table1_Res
ON Table1 (Res) 

-- CREATE TABLE 2 INDEXES 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table2_ID
ON Table2 (ID) 

-- CREATE TABLE 3 INDEXES 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table3_ID
ON Table3 (ID) 

-- CREATE TABLE 4 INDEXES 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table4_ID
ON Table4 (ID) 

-- CREATE TABLE 5 INDEXES 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table5_ID
ON Table5 (ID)
```

Comment: Thank you so much My question is where can I add the above indexes in the above select statement? @Riadhovic

Comment: You don't have to change anything in the above query just execute the my sql code and then run your query

Answer (score 0):

this can give you a basic idea of indexes you will need. Try to look at the ones for your primary keys.

```
    SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS [nvarchar](256)) AS 

[SQLServer]
    ,db.[database_id] AS [DatabaseID]
    ,db.[name] AS [DatabaseName]
    ,id.[object_id] AS [ObjectID]
    ,id.[statement] AS [FullyQualifiedObjectName]
    ,id.[equality_columns] AS [EqualityColumns]
    ,id.[inequality_columns] AS [InEqualityColumns]
    ,id.[included_columns] AS [IncludedColumns]
    ,gs.[unique_compiles] AS [UniqueCompiles]
    ,gs.[user_seeks] AS [UserSeeks]
    ,gs.[user_scans] AS [UserScans]
    ,gs.[last_user_seek] AS [LastUserSeekTime]
    ,gs.[last_user_scan] AS [LastUserScanTime]
    ,gs.[avg_total_user_cost] AS [AvgTotalUserCost]
    ,gs.[avg_user_impact] AS [AvgUserImpact]
    ,gs.[system_seeks] AS [SystemSeeks]
    ,gs.[system_scans] AS [SystemScans]
    ,gs.[last_system_seek] AS [LastSystemSeekTime]
    ,gs.[last_system_scan] AS [LastSystemScanTime]
    ,gs.[avg_total_system_cost] AS [AvgTotalSystemCost]
    ,gs.[avg_system_impact] AS [AvgSystemImpact]
    ,gs.[user_seeks] * gs.[avg_total_user_cost] * (gs.[avg_user_impact] * 0.01) AS [IndexAdvantage]
    ,'CREATE INDEX [Missing_IXNC_' + OBJECT_NAME(id.[object_id], db.[database_id]) + '_' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(id.[equality_columns], ''), ', ', '_'), '[', ''), ']', '') + CASE
        WHEN id.[equality_columns] IS NOT NULL
            AND id.[inequality_columns] IS NOT NULL
            THEN '_'
        ELSE ''
        END + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(id.[inequality_columns], ''), ', ', '_'), '[', ''), ']', '') + '_' + LEFT(CAST(NEWID() AS [nvarchar](64)), 5) + ']' + ' ON ' + id.[statement] + ' (' + ISNULL(id.[equality_columns], '') + CASE
        WHEN id.[equality_columns] IS NOT NULL
            AND id.[inequality_columns] IS NOT NULL
            THEN ','
        ELSE ''
        END + ISNULL(id.[inequality_columns], '') + ')' + ISNULL(' INCLUDE (' + id.[included_columns] + ')', '') AS [ProposedIndex]
    ,CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS [smalldatetime]) AS [CollectionDate]
FROM [sys].[dm_db_missing_index_group_stats] gs WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_db_missing_index_groups] ig WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON gs.[group_handle] = ig.[index_group_handle]
INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_db_missing_index_details] id WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON ig.[index_handle] = id.[index_handle]
INNER JOIN [sys].[databases] db WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON db.[database_id] = id.[database_id]
WHERE id.[database_id] > 4 -- Remove this to see for entire instance

ORDER BY [IndexAdvantage] DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create 4 indexes in the table1:

`IX_Table1_pro , IX_Table1_itype , IX_Table1_itatus , IX_Table1_Res`
using this script (XXX is column name)

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table1_XXX  ON Table1 (XXX)
```

Then create an index in the other tables using the column ID

Comment: Thank you, but can you please tell me more in detail. @Riadhovic

Comment: you need the sql statment to create all the indexes ?

Comment: yes please and I need the sql statement with the indexes in the above query